# Time series plot or different time interval

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot some point in r:

```
k<-c(540, 535, 545, 538, 530, 550, 544, 548)
m<-c(545, 536, 547, 540, 543)
```

for `k`I want to have points from time 1 to 8 on X-axis (difference between tim on x-axis between points are same)

```
plot(k, lwd=2,col="blue",xlab="Time",ylab="Values",pch=16,type="b")
```

but for `m`I would like to have this point on different time. For example on x-axis times (1,2,5,7,8) on the last plot with another color(red). How can I do that?

thanks alot

Comment: `m` has more data points than in `c(1,2,5,7)`

Comment: sorry, I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use `par(new = TRUE)`, something like

```
plot(k, lwd=2,col="blue",xlab="",ylab="",pch=16,type="b")
par(new = TRUE)
plot(c(1,2,5,7,8), m, col="red",xlab="Time",ylab="Values",pch=16,type="b", yaxt = 'n')
```

[image]

Could also just use `lines` instead

```
plot(k, lwd=2,col="blue",xlab="Time",ylab="Values",pch=16,type="b")
lines(c(1,2,5,7,8), m, col="red",pch=16, type="b")
```